# icon fonts not displaying in chrome and firefox when www. prefix is not typed in

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, cross-domain

I have a client's website: *http://www.patriotmobility.com*, which is not displaying icon fonts in chrome and firefox when the URL is typed in as *http://patriotmobility.com* without the www. prefix. Two different font types, font-awesome and social-icons, hosted on the server, not by CDN.

It is a wordpress website which uses the "Bridge" theme. It is hosted on a windows server through applied innovations (Not my choice and they are not helpful at all with their customer service).

I am getting the following warnings when I use inspect element on chrome:

> Font from origin 'Domain Name' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'domain name' is therefore not allowed access

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load domainname/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cx_ajax_callback&mode=get_token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'domain name' is therefore not allowed access

I have combed through stackoverflow and viewed the other discussions on this subject and they don't seem to apply to the specific combination of a wordpress site on a windows server. Many of the discussions are about apache servers and I have tried to apply the various solutions throughout the site discussions including adding the fixes below to the .htaccess file and there is no change.

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "domain name"

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "domainname"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Please help, any solution advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you much!

***** SOLVED: I solved it by directing the non www. prefix to the www. prefix URL through htaccess, turns out the less than adequate server company does not have this in there structure so I had to add it manually. thank you